# Microsoft-Teams: Unable to test personal tab because of "There was a problem reaching this app" error

Tags: microsoft-teams

1. I have created an app using manifest editor where I have generated the ID and I have configured the personal tab to open a public website "https://www.ibm.com/in-en"
2. I have downloaded the zip of the app
3. I have uploaded the app to teams and the app is shown in teams
4. When I click on the app and then click open to load the personal tab, I get the issue as mentioned in the image:

[image: unable to reach app]

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please check if you have the "showloadingindicator" field set to true in your manifest? Could you please try removing it and uploading the app manifest?

Comment: Yes, I made the "showloadingindicator" field to false and it is working now. Thank you

Comment: Great! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and removing the "showLoadingIndicator" fixed it, but while it sorted out the immediate problem, it didn't help understand *why* it was incorrect.

tl;dr : you need to call `microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess()` inside your tab, but if you want more info, see my question/answer over here: [Personal Tab Renders Fine, then a few seconds later shows "There was a problem reaching this app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63765776/personal-tab-renders-fine-then-a-few-seconds-later-shows-there-was-a-problem-r/64048235#64048235)

This wouldn't apply in your case as you're pointing to a public website, but if it was a custom tab, then the fix would help and also allow the "loading" indicator to be used.