# Personal Tab Renders Fine, then a few seconds later shows "There was a problem reaching this app"

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm testing something in a personal tab (something related to SSO, if that's important in context), and the tab renders fine for about 30 seconds or so, then suddenly gets replaced with an error "There was a problem reaching this app" (the one with the image of a woman and a thought bubble). Does anyone know why this suddenly happens AFTER the tab has ALREADY rendered ok?

Comment: I think this might be related to SSO after all. I have the following:

            microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
                successCallback: (result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                failureCallback: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });

and it's entering the failure callback with "resourceDisabled". My App uses Groups.Read.All, but I've granted admin consent (the App is registered in a different tenant to the tenant where I'm testing this)

Comment: Could you please check if you have the "showloadingindicator" field set to true in your manifest? Could you please try removing it and uploading the app manifest?

Comment: Yup, that was it. Obviously I was setting `microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifyAppLoaded();`, but just having the showloadingindicator was enough to bomb the tab. I presume this functionality is still "work in progress". Thanks for the help. Do you want to post it as a proper answer, or would you like me to do it, or something else?

Comment: You can post your answer.

Comment: Ah, I see there's one already, from last month - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873444/microsoft-teams-unable-to-test-personal-tab-because-of-there-was-a-problem-rea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer to this, so posting in case someone else has the issue. Basically, Teams manifest recently added a capability to show a loading / progress indicator to show users that your tab is still loading. It shows up in the manifest as "showLoadingIndicator" and is boolean (true/false). It can also be set in App Studio of course, as the image below shows.

[image]

The problem comes in that the "SDK" link shown in App Studio is flat-out useless - it links to the [Teams js Library on GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js), of all places! It should rather go to [this section of this page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js), which explains how to deal with it. I was originally only calling `microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifyAppLoaded();`, but I needed to also call `microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess()`.