# Teams Messaging Extension with embedded web view - structure of web application

Tags: microsoft-teams

Once again I need help with my messaging extension. I want to show a custom web view within my messaging extension, like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/create-task-module?tabs=dotnet ("With an embedded web view").
I now do not understand how the web application must be written and what the messaging extension is doing/calling in detail. So just entering a normal url will not work, I already tested.
Does anyone can explain which kind of endpoint/structure my web application needs to get successfully called by messaging extension? I'm a little bit confused with the documentation MS provides.

Thanks for your help!

---

UPDATE:
I want to describe more detailed what I'm doing

- after user clicks messaging extension in my bot "OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsyn" is called.
- then the following is executed:

'

```
 var response = new MessagingExtensionActionResponse()
        {
                    Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse()
                    {
                        Value = new TaskModuleTaskInfo()
                        {
                            Height = "large",
                            Width = "large",
                            Title = "Example task module",
                            Url = "https://xxxxxx.eu.ngrok.io/messages/messages",                            
                        },
                    },
                };
                return response;
```

- when I debug my web application on "https://xxxxxx.eu.ngrok.io/messages/messages" I see that MessagesController is called which then wants to display the corresponding view

'

```
public IActionResult Messages()
{
    return View();
}
public MessagesController()
{
}
```

But the page is not showing up. Teams says it cannot reach the app.

---

UPDATE 2

- I added the domain of my web application to "messageHandlers" in manifest, but it doesn't work
- web site is not showing up when user hits message extension
- then I tried another type of ActionResponse (the one that is used for configuration) and that worked

  ```
    return new MessagingExtensionActionResponse
    {
        ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
        {
            Type = "config",
            SuggestedActions = new MessagingExtensionSuggestedAction
            {
                 Actions = new List<CardAction>
                 {
                     new CardAction
                     {
                         Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                         Value = "https://xxxxx.eu.ngrok.io/messages/messages",
                     },
                  },
            },
        },
    };
  ```

---

UPDATE 3

[image: picture 1 - browser dev tools are showing, that connection to website is established]
picture 1 - browser dev tools are showing, that connection to website is established

[image: picture 2 - with dev tools I forced teams to load iframe]
picture 2 - with dev tools I forced teams to load iframe

Comment: Anne, really good troubleshooting steps and updates here - well done and it helped me solve the same problem (although a different root cause, see x-frame-options http header note in my response below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest having a look at the various samples provided for this. There are samples in the Bot Framework sample gallery (https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples) and also in the Teams PnP Samples (https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples). You can also look in the overall Teams Sample gallery viewer at https://pnp.github.io/teams-dev-samples/.

There's a lot of discussion in the comments, but in the end the `showLoadingIndicator` setting was set to `true`, which was a complicating factor in this question as well and needed to be changed (or handled better in the web page - see here for more: [Microsoft-Teams: Unable to test personal tab because of "There was a problem reaching this app" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873444/microsoft-teams-unable-to-test-personal-tab-because-of-there-was-a-problem-rea/62874114#62874114))

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already had a look at the various examples but I 've found non that fits my requirements. I just found the following example: [here](https://camerondwyer.com/2019/09/09/how-to-create-a-microsoft-teams-messaging-extension-pop-up-dialog-with-a-custom-ui/)

Comment: This example in the link is exactly want I want to do but its in typescript ...
I really just want to know what happens in background at the point the user clicks on the messaging extention and the bot reacts with a TaskModuleTaskInfo (with url). I see in browser there is a GET call to the defined url. I suggest the web application should listen for a specific event - but which one?

Comment: It's actually a POST, as the payload contains an Activity object of type "composeExtension/fetchTask", which you need to reply on directly with an `InvokeResponse`. This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/messaging-extension-v3/search-extensions#example-code-in-net

Comment: I had a look at the link but didn't understand what to do :(
I think for me there are some basics missing - and I have lose the thread.

I updated my query with the things I'm doing. So maybe you can help me out with the next step?

Comment: Sounds like good progress...is the website itself running HTTPS? Also, is it listed in the "validDomains" section in your manifest? Those are both very common issues with this area

Comment: Yes it is running with https and also the domain is listed in validDomains. I just wondering why nothing is shown...

Comment: Do you have the domain listed in the "messageHandlers" section as well? You can do it in App Studio or whatever, or right in your schema - search for "messageHandlers" over here to see what it looks like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema

Comment: Hi @Anne, Could you please confirm whether the webpage view is opening up in the browser?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow My domain was not listet in "messageHandlers" and so I added it. But it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Hi @Mallipriya-MSFT, the webpage opens in browser. I can open it in teams in iframe when I trigger config page. See my initial post, section UPDATE2
So, I think there must be something wrong with TaskModuleContinueResponse. Or are there other requirements in web application for TaskModuleContinueResponse?

Comment: I still found no possibilty to show up my website when user clicks on messaging extension. So I had a deeper look with dev tools in browser. Please see pictures in UPDATE3 in my initial post. I was able to see that javascript code of my website is executed (see picture 1) and also that the iframe exists but is hidden. When I force iframe to be displayed (see picture 2) it is displayed next to error message from teams. Anyone has an idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have "showLoadingIndicator" set to "true"?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Thats it! "showLoadingIndicator" was set to true and I changed it to false and now my website is displayed. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: great, glad to help! Please upvote/mark as answer, so others can see this was useful. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The original question with its updates shows some awesome troubleshooting. Opening Teams in a browser and using the dev tools to see if it's making a GET to your URL was really helpful.

In my case, my web server was adding this HTTP header, which was problematic since Teams uses an iframe for its UI:

```
x-frame-options: DENY
```

Once I removed that, it started working.