# Failing to get the renewal token from teams microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({ }) on app load or for renewal when it expires

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a personal app , it is failing to get the auth token from this method

microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({ }) , it is failing often, the below attached the images from the console. it is taking time to get the token and on browser refresh/retry it is working

[Renewal token failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzLV9.png)

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
    if (inTeams) {
      microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifyAppLoaded()
      microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
        successCallback: (result) => {
          microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess()
        },
        failureCallback: (error) => {
          microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifyFailure({
            reason: microsoftTeams.appInitialization.FailedReason.AuthFailed
          })
          console.log('Failed to Authenticate')
        }
      })
    }
  }, [inTeams])
```

I can see the token renewal message appearing on console for sometime, is there any fall back mechanism to handle to the token renewal operation if it fails, We are getting the token on retry button of refreshing of the browser,
[retry button of the teams screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CO3U.png)

whenever the teams token renewal fails how do I show a custom screen rather the default team failure screen,

I have tried adding a hook in the failure sate and enable component but that does not seems to work.

```
failureCallback: (error) => {
          microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifyFailure({
            reason: microsoftTeams.appInitialization.FailedReason.AuthFailed
          })
          setIsTeamAuthToken(false)}

  return(<div> {!isTeamAuthToken && <h1> Failed to get Teams auth token </h1> } </div>)
```

is it because I have added notify Failure method in side the failure call back.
can i know if we have an alternate way to get the token

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused between SSO in a tab, and the way the "loading" indicator works. For simplicity sake, for now, set `showLoadingIndicator` to `false`, and then remove your `notifySuccess` and `notifyFailure` calls. See this question for more info: [Microsoft-Teams: Unable to test personal tab because of "There was a problem reaching this app" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873444/microsoft-teams-unable-to-test-personal-tab-because-of-there-was-a-problem-rea/62874114#62874114)

Comment: hi Hilton Giesenow, It is not often, it happens when we login for the first time in a day, so showLoadingIndicator matters ?

Comment: I was able to see 'Failed to Authenticate' error message which i had added in the `notifyFailure`  method

Comment: The loading indicator is not a requirement to use at all - it's only a way built in to Teams if you have something that takes a while to load, like getting data from a backend API. In that case, `notifySuccess` tells Teams that whatever you were waiting for is now done. If Teams doesn't receive a `notifySuccess` call within 30 seconds, it automatically shows the 'fail' screen. I would not use this mechanism for login success/failure, as it doesn't let you handle the login very nicely.

Comment: Separately, if the 'silent' login fails, then you can show a "login" button that the user can click on, which will start the login popup/redirect process. So, instead of `notifyFailure`, rather set a state in your react component to show a message and a 'login' button.